# Equivalent for Windows 7 "mklink" on OS X?

Tags: macos, symbolic-link, dropbox, hardlink

Is there a feature on OS X that does the same as `mklink` under Windows 7? It can create symbolic links and hard links.

I have just read about this tool to have Dropbox sync an application folder by combining it with `mklink` on Windows 7, **using a hard link**:

http://www.hackingfreaks.in/2011/01/9-amazing-software-mashups-killer-free.html

How can I achieve this on OS X?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`. Run `ln` for a short description and `man ln` for the documentation.

Example:

```
ln existing.txt new.txt
```

For folders, create a symbolic link using `ln -s`:

```
ln -s existing new
```

As per Scott's comment, these *symbolic links* [work with Dropbox on OS X](https://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/sync-other-folders)

---

*Hardlinks* on folders are [possible but difficult](//stackoverflow.com/q/80875), and insanely dangerous if you mess it up (they don't like recursion).

Comment: Use a symlink to sync folders outside your Dropbox on Mac OS X (and Linux for that matter). It works fine, and you avoid the whole can of worms that hard linking directories is. See http://wiki.dropbox.com/TipsAndTricks/SyncOtherFolders

Answer (score 0):

Not so Equivalent like mklink.

ls -s /tmp/a /tmp/b

If I open project using CLion and select /tmp/b, I'll see it finally recognized as /tmp/a. The title bar of the window displays the path it "think".

While under windows, mklink /j c:\b c:\a will indeed make all applications think files in 'c:\b' not 'c:\a'.

Use CLion do the same thing:
Open project in c:\b, the title bar will display "c:\b...".

This is the desired behavior a symbol link should be.

However, macOS cannot do this correctly.