# Symlink to Files & Dirs in Dropbox

Tags: git, symbolic-link, dropbox, alias

I just installed Dropbox on my Mac, so now I have this Dropbox folder in my home directory.

I only have the free plan (2 GB), so I can't just throw all my files & directories in there.

I currently store all my projects in my `~/Projects` directory.

Should I just move files I want to store into Dropbox, or should I also create a symlink `ln -s` (or should I use Mac Alias instead?) so that I can also access the file outside of my Dropbox directory?

I'm thinking if I move a whole project to the dropbox that's cool. But, in some cases, I might only want to Dropbox some of the files in a project, in which case I'll also want to have those files inside the project directory, esp. since I usually track my individual projects with Git.

How do you do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent for Windows 7 "mklink" on OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/231840/equivalent-for-windows-7-mklink-on-os-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dropbox help has an [article](http://wiki.dropbox.com/TipsAndTricks/SyncOtherFolders) about this.

The rest of your question is subjective and argumentative. Do you have more specific requirements?

Answer (score 1):

I just keep my git repositories in Dropbox. Dropbox doesn't seem to have any issue with conflicts... or at least I haven't experienced any problems with keeping git repos on Dropbox for the last year or so.

Why would you want to access files outside the Dropbox directory?

Comment: Thanks. Well, I guess I'm just used to having them in the `~/Projects` directory and have some `~/.bash_profile` deploy scripts and such that rely on that. Not a big deal though. But, if I didn't have enough storage to store the whole project, then I could just symlink to a few of the files in the project.

Comment: Yeah very true -- dropbox follows symlinks so you're good. Also since I code on two computers, I like to keep all my configuration on dropbox: ~/.bash_profile -> /Users/me/Dropbox/code/dotfiles/.bash_profile